# ERROR PHP session_start(); No encuenta el archivo en un directorio

Tags: php, apache, session

Cuando quiero iniciar sesión en mi proyecto me muestra este error, ya he buscado esta carpeta y he verificado en el archivo de php.ini y todo esta correcto. Muchas gracias!!

> Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp\sess_585rmso0idoue6q48ts79uhakp,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Bincode\connection\connection.php on line 2
>
> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path:
>   /tmp) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Bincode\connection\connection.php on line 2

[image]
Esta es la conexión

[image]
Y este es el error que me muestra

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','bincode');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert(
                <?php printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                        exit(); 
                ?>
            );window.location.href='../';
        </script>
    <?php

}
```

?>

Gracias de antemano por toda la ayuda, soy nuevo en esto

He probado lo que han dicho
[image]
Pero sigue igual
[image]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
include '../connection/connection.php';
if ($_POST['op'] == 'login') {
$usuari = $con->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['usuario']));
$contrasenia = $con->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['contrasenia']));
$sesion = 0;
$blocked = 1;
if (empty($usuari) || empty($contrasenia)) {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('CAMPOS VACIOS');window.location.href='../';
        </script>
    <?php
    exit();
}  
$pass_m = md5($contrasenia);
$consulta = $con->prepare("SELECT usuario, pass, nivel FROM usuario WHERE usuario = ? AND pass = ? AND sesion = ? AND blocked = ?");
$consulta->bind_param('ssii',$usuari,$pass_m,$sesion,$blocked);
$consulta->execute();
$consulta->store_result();
$consulta->bind_result($usuario,$pass,$nivel);
if ($consulta->fetch()) {} 
if($consulta->num_rows > 0){
    if ($usuari === $usuario && $pass_m === $pass && $nivel === "ADMINISTRADOR") {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass_m;
        $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel;
        $session = $con->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET sesion = 1, welcome = 1 WHERE usuario = ?");
        $session->bind_param('s',$usuario);
        if (!$session->execute()) {
            echo "2";
            exit();
        }
        $session->close();
        echo "1";
    }elseif ($usuari === $usuario && $pass_m === $pass && $nivel === "ASESOR") {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass_m;
        $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel;
        $session = $con->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET sesion = 1, welcome = 1 WHERE usuario = ?");
        $session->bind_param('s',$usuario);
        if (!$session->execute()) {
            echo "2";
            exit();
        }
        $session->close();
        echo "1";
    }elseif ($usuari === $usuario && $pass_m === $pass && $nivel === "CLIENTE") {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass_m;
        $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel;
        $session = $con->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET sesion = 1, welcome = 1 WHERE usuario = ?");
        $session->bind_param('s',$usuario);
        if (!$session->execute()) {
            echo "2";
            exit();
        }
        $session->close();
        echo "1";
    }elseif ($usuari === $usuario && $pass_m === $pass && $nivel === "PS") {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass_m;
        $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel;
        $session = $con->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET sesion = 1, welcome = 1 WHERE usuario = ?");
        $session->bind_param('s',$usuario);
        if (!$session->execute()) {
            echo "2";
            exit();
        }
        $session->close();
        echo "1";
    }else {
        ?>
            <script>
                alert('ERROR NO SE A ENCONTRADO TU NIVEL');window.location.href='../';
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}else {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('ERROR NO SE A ENCONTRADO TU USUARIO');window.location.href='../';
        </script>
    <?php
}

$consulta->close();
```

}
?>

Comment: Hola, no tiene nada que ver la sesión. No encuentra el fichero, revisa la ortografía y las mayúsculas. Tambien la barra invertida. (/ o \)

Comment: Pero ya e revisado la carpeta donde supuestamente esta el archivo y si encuentra

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, pon el código y una captura de pantalla por favor ;)

Comment: Amigo, recuerda que es importante que incluyas el código, no una imagén del código, así podemos ayudarte más fácil. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Así esta bien, porque es una de mis primeras veces en pedir ayuda

Comment: prueba cambiando esto: if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {

Comment: Yo estoy probando tal como lo tienes, y funciona sin pete ni nada. Que version tienes de PHP?

Comment: 7.3.6, pero no se que es lo malo porque en un host si me deja iniciar sesión y descargo los mismos archivo solo que de forma local me arroja este error

Comment: Veo que estas usando un IDE, no se cual es, pero yo estoy probando esto en produccion (real) y no peta. Tiene pinta de ser un error del servidor que se monta con el IDE. Solo son warning no deberia de afectar a la ejecucion del codigo. Por otro lado en el codigo que no enseñas no veo ningun mensaje  'Usuario no encontrado'

Comment: Utilizo Visual Studio Code, y ese mensaje lo uso en el archivo que uso para validar la sesión, ahora les adjunto una captura con el codigo

Comment: Ok, a ver ya por ultimo, hazte un PHP que destruya sesiones y luego lanza este. Ya me dices! hasta mañana

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, lo he hecho pero no funciona, feliz día y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Tiene los permisos php para escribir el /tmp? Quiza pueda ser eso.  otra opcion seria que buscases el php.ini y cambiases el directorio donde se guardan las sesiones a uno donde tengas permisos 100%, el path se pone en esta linea: "session.save_path =" y se encuentra dentro del php.ini

Comment: Si tengo todos los permisos y no, no cambie nada en ese archivo

Comment: Conseguiste solucionarlo?

Comment: No, aun me tira el mismo error